# WAS 9 migration issue ContextNotActiveException

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2.2, websphere-8, myfaces

After migrating WAS 8 to WAS 9 , we are using J2EE , JSF 2.2 MyFaces ,myfaces-extcdi and delta spike.

Caused by:

```
org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.scope.conversation.WindowScoped
```

Comment: Post the gereric pieces of the error in a search engine of your liking and add 'site:stackoverflow.com' to it

Comment: Are you bundling your own MyFaces implementation?  If so it will not have integration with the CDI implementation provided with WebSphere.

Comment: How I can bundle my own MyFaces , myfaces-extcdi and deltaspike on Websphere 9 application server